# Reading successive three columns from file into array

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am coding a basic python program about reading 3D coordinate from a text file and pass it into the array.
Here is a portion of my text file.

```
1              0.20069808    0.70680627    0.00000000
2              1.66069808    0.70680627    0.00000000
3              0.20069808    2.16680627    0.00000000
...
```

I have been trying myself and the following is my experiment

```
coord_raw = []
x = []
y = []
z = []

for line in f:
    lst = line.split()
    print(lst[1])
    x.append(lst[1])
    y.append(lst[2])
    z.append(lst[3])
    coord_raw.append((x, y, z))

    #coord_raw += [x, y, z]
```

What I expect is the following

```
[[0.20069808,0.70680627,0.00000000]
 [1.66069808,0.70680627,0.00000000]
 [0.20069808,2.16680627,0.00000000]
 ...                           ...]
 ...                           ...]]
```

But, it shows an error

```
     x.append(lst[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can anyone help me to figure out this problem and comment me how can I make my code easier and faster? 

I appreciate any helps.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should consider using numpy:

```
import numpy as np    
arr = np.loadtxt(filepath)
np.delete(arr, 0, 1) # deletes the first column of 0, 1, 2, 3
```

As a numpy array will be much easier to work with on numeric data

Comment: 2 interesting points to notice here: (1)what if the file has more than 3 lines. (2) if data aren't numbers

Comment: (1) No problem, it will load everything. (2) In principle: no problem, but you might consider using `pandas.read_csv` (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), which has much more flexibility and loads everything in its own column

Comment: (1) yes, i know, i meant that he may want only 3 rows (think what he wanted in the question.. )

Comment: Ahh, just use `arr[:3, :]`

Answer (score 1):

The most basic solution is to read this as followed:

```
import csv

data = []
with open('input.csv') as f:
    for line in csv.reader(f, delimiter=' '):
        data.append(tuple(line))
print(data)
```

on input file:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

You'll get:

```
[(1,2,3)
 (4,5,6)
 (7,8,9)]
```

**If you are using numbers:**
best solution for you will be using `numpy` (don't really know your usage..)

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly, it doesn't throw an error to me. This is what I get when I run your code (unless the row names, `1, 2, 3...` are actually not a column of their own on the text file).

```
[(['0.20069808', '1.66069808', '0.20069808'],
  ['0.70680627', '0.70680627', '2.16680627'],
  ['0.00000000', '0.00000000', '0.00000000']),
 (['0.20069808', '1.66069808', '0.20069808'],
  ['0.70680627', '0.70680627', '2.16680627'],
  ['0.00000000', '0.00000000', '0.00000000']),
 (['0.20069808', '1.66069808', '0.20069808'],
  ['0.70680627', '0.70680627', '2.16680627'],
  ['0.00000000', '0.00000000', '0.00000000'])]
```

Comment: Could you please change the first column 1, 2, 3, .. to a character or string, i.e., A, B, C, ... ?